# Не могу запустить React приложение на хостинге

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Создал приложение через `create react app`. Проблемы начались при переносе приложения на хостинг. Сейчас не могу запустить приложение и `npm start` и `npm run build` отображают ошибку:

> portfolio@0.1.0 build /home/s50962/public_html/sepezho.ru
>    react-scripts build
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0
>   build: `react-scripts build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
>   Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 build script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/s50962/.npm/_logs/2019-10-04T09_04_03_659Z-debug.log

Если нужны логи, пишите.